# How to get the index/key of the selected item in the list Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using `ListTile` to create each item in the list. Each item is created dynamically from the data array. `ListTile` provides `onTap`, but it's insufficient for me, because I need to find out which item is clicked by either getting the key or index.

ListTile:

```
     new ListTile(
        //leading: const Icon(Icons.flight_land),
        title: const Text('Trix\'s airplane'),
        subtitle:  const Text('The airplane is only in Act II.'),
        enabled: true,
        onTap: () { //TODO: get the identifier for this item },
        trailing: new Container(
          child: new Row(
            children: [
              new Text("70%"),
              const Icon(Icons.flight_land)
]
)
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would want to build your list of `ListTile`s within a `ListView`, and use `List.generate` constructor to get the index of the `children` here is a simple example:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class ListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListTestState createState() => new _ListTestState();
}

class _ListTestState extends State<ListTest> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _id;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("List"),),
      body: new ListView(
          children: new List.generate(10, (int index){
            return new ListTile(title: new Text("item#$index"),
            onTap:(){
              setState((){
                _id = index; //if you want to assign the index somewhere to check
              });
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("You clicked item number $_id")));
            },
            );
          })

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `List.generate` works fine with small lists, if you are reading in an extendable list (e.g: a list of users) you need to use `ListView.builder` instead of a `ListView` it has a `builder` argument that allow you to loop over your list by index as well.

```
new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        //return your list
      },
```

Comment: wrong answer. you are using builder. the widget created using listile

Answer (score 6):

You can create ListTile instances with closures that capture item information. In this example, the _tappedFolder function is called with the label of each Text of the ListTile.

```
  List<ListTile> _buildFolderTiles() {
    var list = List<ListTile>();
    for (var each in ['A:','B:','C:','D:']) {
      list.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(each),
        onTap: (){ _tappedFolder(each); }
      ));
    }
    return list;
  }

  void _tappedFolder(String which) {
    print("tapped ${which}");
  }
```