# How can I get the row-ID or row-number in a ListTile?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have a long list of ListTiles in flutter, how can I get the row-number.. is there a row-identifier?

There is no code to show. This is just a general question.

Please reconsider before giving me a negative vote..I will lose access to StackOverview, and I've made so many friends already.

Comment: Hi, Kiro. In regards to your last paragraph, take care about your questions and put some effort on them, since we also need to put effort into answering your question. In stackoverflow, we value questions with some effort, maybe some code of what you tried, or where you need what you're asking, some information that your have tried to search somewhere (like the docs for ListTile). It's also good to make clear what your objective is. and where is it that you're trying to use it. Don't worry about downvotes. I know people here sometimes are rude, but it's not personal. Take care :)

Comment: Now, off to the question: how are you building your list? Do you have ListView.builder(), or do you have a loop, or an array of list tiles? There are a few ways to do that, mostly you'd have to pass the index number while you build your list, like a parameter with the index you're using. If you show us some code maybe we can help properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the index/key of the selected item in the list Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085070/how-to-get-the-index-key-of-the-selected-item-in-the-list-flutter)

Comment: May be it's duplicated from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085070/how-to-get-the-index-key-of-the-selected-item-in-the-list-flutter). And a short answer you cannot do that without `ListView.builder()`, as @George said.

Comment: @ShadyBoshra ok. No problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `ListView.builder` to accomplish this. The sample code would look like this:

```
List<...> items = ... //fill in whatever you need
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return buildRow(index);
                  },
)
```

Then in your buildRow method you will have this onTapStatement

```
Widget buildRow(int index) {
    return ListTile(
        title: ..., //whatever you want, you can get data from sample list by
                   //doing items[index]
        onTap: () {
            //do what you want and your row number is index.
        } 
    );
}
```